# (Bumblebee) Any GPU related commands totally freeze system when gpu is powered off via bbswitch

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, freeze, gpu

I own an Asus Rog Strix Scar III - model G531GV which runs a side by side installation of Parrot OS together with the already installed Windows 10 OS.

After a lot of struggle and numerous hard resets, I managed to configure Bumblebee up to the point that optirun/primusrun commands work as they should, use machine's GPU, and when the command completes bbswitch kicks in and completely powers off GPU, that way power management support is in place.

```
cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch -> 0000:01:00.0 OFF
```

While that's what I wanted to accomplish in the first place I soon realized that while GPU is powered off by bbswitch, any GPU related commands like:

```
nvidia-smi
lspci -k
```

etc, completely freeze my computer. The cursor stops responding, no shortcut that could drop me into any kind of TTY sessions work, and in general nothing works besides powering off the machine through power button. Moreover, I can't even check what is getting recorded in syslog regarding this error since nothing is there when I reboot the computer.

My system specifics are the following:

```
    Laptop model       : Asus Rog Strix Scar III - G531GV
    Installed OS       : Parrot 4.9 64-bit (full updated)
    Kernel             : Linux 5.5.0-1parrot1-amd64 x86_64
    Nvidia Gpu         : RTX-2060 6GB
    Nvidia-Drivers     : Latest - Proprietary 440.82
    Bumblebeed Version : 3.2.1
```

I would be more than happy to issue any requested commands to finally overcome this nightmare. I've gone through numerous posts and tried many different things like grub parameters but nothing seems to make a difference. I'm really stuck at this point for more than ten days or so.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you

```
rmmod nvidia
```

before you power off the GPU using bbswitch.

You also need to:

```
optirun nvidia-smi
```

or

```
optirun lspci -k
```

You should be able to alias it in your .bashrc

Comment: Hello Gordan Bobic, thank you a lot for your fast reply. 
I just tried: `sudo tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<ON` to power up nvidia so i could try what you suggested. Then I issued `sudo rmmod nvidia`
and result of this command was: `rmmod: ERROR: Module nvidia is not currently loaded`. I believe that any nvidia modules are unloaded as they should otherwise bbswitch would complain about not being able to power of the GPU.

Comment: Fair enough. I suspect you are out of luck, then. The problem comes down to the fact that the Nvidia device is present enough to show it's device ID and the functionality required to power it up, and not present enough to actually do anything more than that. So the programs in question detect it, then find out the hard way that it is unresponsive. I seem to recall seeing a problem like this on 10xx and later series GPUs. I can't reproduce it on my 970M, that just errors out on the device. Presumably Nvidia implemented extra power savings since and the price to pay is the behaviour you see.

Comment: Added a workaround method to the original answer.

Comment: Wow i just realized that `primusrun lspci -k` and `primusrun nvidia-smi` both freeze my computer as well while GPU is powered off through `bbswitch`.. Thats something i get to know for the first time. Now the strange part is that `optirun lspci -k` and `optirun nvidia-smi` both work as expected. Moreover, any command executes successfully when nvidia is powered up. I'm really confused..

Comment: Quick Update: `primusrun glxgears` and `optirun glxgears`, execute as expected

Comment: `primusrun` and `optirun` do things a little differently. The general gist of it holds, though. The only workaround is to alias in those commands to make sure the GPU device is powered up for them.

Comment: Does that mean that there is not a general fix about this and I'll have to alias every single command that freeze my computer? I somehow believe that this is bbswitch's fault, or some kind of misconfiguration that I fail to identify.

Comment: According to `https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ`:
`How to know if my graphics card is supported?
Bumblebee has two parts: power management and the ability to run programs using the discrete card. The first feature is supported with bbswitch which should be able to support all Optimus models. The ability to use the nvidia card depends on the driver: open-source nouveau and proprietary nvidia.` 
Well, nvidia proprietary drivers 440.82 include support for my GPU model and bbswitch supports all optimus models as it was mentioned.

Comment: If there is anything else i could possibly try or tweak, i would be in for it 100%

Comment: Sadly, no, there is no one-thing-fixes-all approach to this. Anything that probes the PCI bus is going to hit this, and the only alternative is to not use bbswitch and have the Nvidia GPU powered up all the time. That will "just work", but it'll cost you battery life.

Comment: Hey, sry for late reply. I've managed to fix things by abandoning completely the bumblebee project and moving on to the official nvidia's approach for optimus laptops - nvidia prime gpu render offload. This way iGPU (low power consumption) is always in charge until i insert the special command that orders nvidia GPU to execute the command i wish to run. Moreover, in this approach nvidia GPU doesn't really gets disabled at all, driver puts GPU on low power consumption until GPU is needed for a task to execute. The aforementioned freeze problems are gone as well since nvidia is always enabled.